# Converting MSTest to NUnit: CurrentTestOutcome and UnitTestOutcome alternatives in NUnit

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, mstest

I am converting the following code from MSTest V2 to NUnit 3. Can you help me find the alternatives of CurrentTestOutcome and UnitTestOutcome in NUnit?

```
var status = MyTestContext.CurrentTestOutcome;

switch (status)
{
    case UnitTestOutcome.Failed:
        TheLogger.Error($"Test Failed => {MyTestContext.FullyQualifiedTestClassName}");
        CurrentTestCase.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
        CurrentTestCase.Fail("Fail");
        break;
    case UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive:
        CurrentTestCase.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
        CurrentTestCase.Warning("Inconclusive");
        break;
    case UnitTestOutcome.Unknown:
        CurrentTestCase.Skip("Test skipped");
        break;
    default:
        CurrentTestCase.Pass("Pass");
        break;
}
```

I am switching based on current test case outcome. I have found that  MyTestContext.Result.Outcome is alternative for MyTestContext.CurrentTestOutcome in NUnit but what will be the alternative for  UnitTestOutcome.Inconclusive etc in NUnit? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `TestStatus` in `TestContext`

```
var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;

switch (status)
{
    case TestStatus.Inconclusive:
        break;
    case TestStatus.Skipped:
        break;
    case TestStatus.Passed:
        break;
    case TestStatus.Failed:
        break;
    case TestStatus.Warning:
        break;
}
```

Comment: There's also `TestStatus.Warning`